# How to replace accents in a column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, unicode, decode

I have a dataframe `dataSwiss` which contains the information Swiss municipalities. I want to replace the letter with accents with normal letter.

This is what I am doing:

```
dataSwiss['Municipality'] = dataSwiss['Municipality'].str.encode('utf-8')
dataSwiss['Municipality'] = dataSwiss['Municipality'].str.replace(u"é", "e")
```

but I get the following error:

```
----> 2 dataSwiss['Municipality'] = dataSwiss['Municipality'].str.replace(u"é", "e")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

data looks like:

```
dataSwiss.Municipality
0               Zürich
1               Zürich
2               Zürich
3               Zürich
4               Zürich
5               Zürich
6               Zürich
7               Zürich
```

I found the solution

```
s = dataSwiss['Municipality']
res = s.str.decode('utf-8')
res = res.str.replace(u"é", "e")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one way. You can convert to byte literal first before decoding to utf-8.

```
s = pd.Series(['hello', 'héllo', 'Zürich', 'Zurich'])

res = s.str.normalize('NFKD')\
       .str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')\
       .str.decode('utf-8')

print(res)

0     hello
1     hello
2    Zurich
3    Zurich
dtype: object
```

[`pd.Series.str.normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.normalize.html) uses [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) module. As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize):

> The normal form KD (NFKD) will apply the compatibility decomposition,
>   i.e. replace all compatibility characters with their equivalents.

Comment: What I get instead of `Zurich` is `ZA14rich`

Comment: @emax, That's strange, are you copy / pasting my code exactly? I'm on Pandas 0.19.2 / Python 3.6 for reference. What are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Try  **unidecode** module.

**Ex:**

```
import unidecode
dataSwiss['Municipality'] = dataSwiss['Municipality'].apply(unidecode.unidecode)
```

Or:

```
import unicodedata
def remove_accents(input_str):
    nfkd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)
    only_ascii = nfkd_form.encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
    return only_ascii

dataSwiss['Municipality'] = dataSwiss['Municipality'].apply(remove_accents)
```

**Note:** The function is from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)

*Update as per comment*

```
dataSwiss['Municipality'] = dataSwiss['Municipality'].apply(unicode).apply(remove_accents)
```

Comment: Now I receive this error 
`----> 3     nfkd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)` `TypeError: normalize() argument 2 must be unicode, not str`

Comment: @Still the same, I do not understand why

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: I posted a sample of the data