# Not able to use imported package on a dataframe column in PySpark (version 2.4.4) and Python version 3.6.8

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In my AWS cluster, I have downloaded a Python package:

```
  python3 -m pip install Unidecode
```

Now, I want to use this on my pyspark dataframe column named '**city**' which take values like: 'são paulo', 'seropédica' etc *(i.e with accents)* and want to create a new column named '**city_no_accents**' which will correct all accents from the text and make it in normal English text like 'sao paulo', 'seropedica' etc.

So, I wrote below PySpark code:

```
<...imported some other packages>
from unidecode import unidecode

def remove_accents(data):
    return unidecode(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #create spark session
    spark = SparkSession.sparkSession("GetData")
    sc = spark.getSparkSession()
    logging.info("Spark Session initiated")
    sm = sparkManager.sparkManager(sc)
    remove_accents_udf = udf(remove_accents)

city_df_with_accents = city_df['city'] 

city_df_without_accents = city_df_with_accents.withColumn('city_no_accents', remove_accents_udf('city'))

city_df_without_accents.show(5)
```

Last line in above code is giving me below ERROR:

> File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 580, in loads
> return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unidecode'

But if in place of a dataframe column, I take a string variable then it is working fine. For Example:

```
x = 'são paulo'
remove_accents_udf(x)
```

> OUTPUT:   'sao paulo'

So, is there a way by which I could convert all the rows of a particular dataframe column (i.e 'city') into plain text?

PySpark ==> version 2.4.4

Python  ==> version 3.6.8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to remove accents with Apache Spark dataframes in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359534/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-with-apache-spark-dataframes-in-pyspark)

Comment: No, again I will be stuck with the same issue so it won't work. I have posted a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I found 1 solution (might not be an optimal one though)

First convert the PySpark Data Frame into Pandas Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import * 

city_geolocation_mappings_results_df_pd = city_geolocation_mappings_results_df.toPandas()
```

> Then make use of this ticket: [How to replace accents in a column of a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50253753/how-to-replace-accents-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Then convert back Pandas DF to PySpark DF.